# Как отключить Яндекс Метрику в Яндекс "Поделиться"?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

В связи с блокировкой на Украине сервисов яндекс, счетчики в консоль выбивают ошибки. Саму Яндекс метрику уже сделали в обход через Амазон, а вот в "Поделиться" стоит старая ссылка на метрику, и она продолжает выбивать ошибку.

Можно как то отключить в "Поделиться" обращение к странице яндекс метрики `https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js`. Это и на будущее пригодится, ведь зачем два раза одно и тоже, если метрика уже была подключена на сайте.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Хорошая идея. Думаю, сделаем в течение пары дней.

Comment: Готово, теперь скрипт не загружается дважды.